# Trying to understand the proof for complements of subspaces of finite codimension

Tags: general-topology, quotient-spaces

I'm trying to read through the book "Introduction to Global Variational Geometry" by Demeter Krupka and I don't fully understand a proof regarding the existence of a topological complememnt for a subspace with finite codimension. More specifically the Lemma is as following:

[image]

I don't understand the part where he says "we choose in the coset $\xi_k$ and arbitrary element $x_k \in X$".

How is $\xi_k$ a coset? Wasn't it a basis element?

Could someone clarify?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The elements of $X/M$ are the cosets of $M$.

Comment: ok, for some reason I thought $X/M$ was the complement of $M$ in $X$, apparently it was just the quotient set all along. Thanks @DanielFischer

Comment: I recall a harsh discussion here at math.SE about notation for set difference, the OP claiming that $/$ was a usual one. Now I realize that how damaging is that convention.